# Convert keys of JSON dictionary that are strings of ints to ints

Tags: python, json

I want to convert the keys of the following dictionary that are strings of ints to ints once the dictionary is JSON deserialized. I tried specifying the `json.loads` option `parse_int`, but this did not work.

```
>>> d = {'1' : 2, '2':3, "a" : 3}
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(d), parse_int = int)
{'2': 3, 'a': 3, '1': 2}
```

The desired output is `{1: 2, 2: 3, 'a': 3}`

Comment: Loop through the object using for...in and create a new object.
Use parseInt() on the keys and use the returned values as keys in the new object.

Comment: The reason `parse_int` isn't working for you is, those keys are actually strings. `parse_int` is used to parse JSON integers, not JSON strings that look like integers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import json
d = {'1' : 2, '2':3, "a" : 3}
j = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
output_dict = {}
for k, v in j.items():
    try:
        output_dict[int(k)] = v
    except ValueError:
        output_dict[k] = v

print output_dict
```

Result:
`{u'a': 3, 1: 2, 2: 3}`

Comment: There is no need to use `parse_int` in your solution.

Comment: _____fixed_____